# Panadas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

When trying to use the pd.pivot_table on a given dataset, I noticed that it creates levels for all existing levels on a parent group, not all possible levels. For example, on a dataset like this:

[image]

```
    YEAR    CLASS
0   2013    A
1   2013    A
2   2013    B
3   2013    B
4   2013    B
5   2013    C
6   2013    C
7   2013    D
8   2014    A
9   2014    A
10  2014    A
11  2014    B
12  2014    B
13  2014    B
14  2014    C
15  2014    C
```

there is no level D for year 2014, so the pivot table will look like this:

```
pd.pivot_table(d,index=["YEAR","CLASS"],values=["YEAR"],aggfunc=[len],fill_value=0)
```

[image]

```
len
YEAR    CLASS   
2013    A   2
        B   3
        C   2
        D   1
2014    A   3
        B   3
        C   2
```

What I want is to get a separate group for D in 2014 with length 0 in my pivot table. How can I include all possible levels in the child variable for the parent variable?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please post a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) and [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
print pd.pivot_table(df,
                     index=["YEAR","CLASS"],
                     values=["YEAR"],
                     aggfunc=[len],
                     fill_value=0)

            len
YEAR CLASS     
2013 A        2
     B        3
     C        2
     D        1
2014 A        3
     B        3
     C        2

print pd.crosstab(df['YEAR'],df['CLASS'])
CLASS  A  B  C  D
YEAR             
2013   2  3  2  1
2014   3  3  2  0

df = pd.crosstab(df['YEAR'],df['CLASS']).stack()
df.name = 'len'
print df
YEAR  CLASS
2013  A        2
      B        3
      C        2
      D        1
2014  A        3
      B        3
      C        2
      D        0
Name: len, dtype: int64
```